# How to replace markdown code indentation with backticks in RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I have a bunch of content that looks like:

```
content

    test test
        testing
    hello

content
```

The goal is to use RegEx to convert it to look like:

````
content

```
test test
    testing
hello
```

content
````

So just replacing code blocks that are done with indentation with the backtick version for code blocks.

I've tried the RegEx expression: `(    ((?:\S| )*)\n)+` with a replacement string of the following:

````
```\n$0```\n
````

Problem with that is it doesn't remove the one level of indentation in the code block.

How can I build a regular expression to do this?

One more note, using JavaScript to do this regular expression.

Here is a RegEx101 file that I've tried to work on: https://regex101.com/r/iMbDly/1

Comment: `.replace(/\n\n((?: {4}.*\n)+)\n/g, (_, markup) => \`\n\n\\`\\`\\`\n${markup.replace(/^ {4}/gm, '')}\\`\\`\\`\n\n\`)` - not sure if it works in all scenarios, would need to be tested a bit. Would at least need a special case for when the markup is at the beginning of the text, and doesn't have an empty line preceding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested replaces. The outer one for the block of code, the nested one to remove leading whitespace:

````js
let input = `content

    test test
        testing
    hello

content`;
let result = input.replace(/(\n {4}[^\n]*)+/g, function(m) {
  return '\n```' + m.replace(/\n {4}/g, '\n') + '\n```';
});
console.log(result);
````

Output: (leading `.` added to escape SO rendering)

````
content

.```
test test
    testing
hello
.```

content
````

Explanation of outer regex `/(\n {4}[^\n]*)+/g`:

- `(` - capture group (you could use non-capture group `(?:...)`)

  - `\n` - newline (if you want to support a code block at the very beginning use `(?:^|\n)` instead)
  - `{4}` - four spaces
  - `[^\n]*` - everything else on same line
- `)+` - capture group end, repeated 1+ times
- replace is a function passing along the matched text
- use `g` flag for multiple code blocks

Explanation of inner regex `/\n {4}/g`:

- `\n` - newline
- `{4}` - four spaces
- replace with newline and three backticks
- use `g` flag to fix all code block lines

Comment: Unless you add the dotall flag `s`, `.` doesn't match newline, so `[^\n]`, while working fine, is a bit verbose.

Comment: @ASDFGerte: I did not use the `s` flag because it is not universally supported (unless you use a specific regex library such as XRegExp.)

Comment: @Charlie Fish: Does this fit your needs? Any questions?

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, this is exactly what I needed :)